# Is there a complete eclipse package?

Tags: java, php, c, eclipse, download

Until now I used Netbeans and want to try eclipse now.

I went to the eclipse site and wanted to download it. I am totally confused with the package.
There are different packages for C, Java, PHP ... development. Well I want to develop in all these languages and in addition in PERL and Python.

When I download one of these packages, do I have to add plugins for all the other languages, or is there a general package, which is packed with many plugins?

Comment: What do you want to use it for?  Eclipse is a powertool so you only want some of the functionality anyway.

Comment: I am developing software in c, java, php, perl and python... I was used to have a gneral support of c, java and php in Netbeans without installing plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a ready-made package that contains support for everything.

You can download one of the packages and add support for other languages, frameworks etc. later by installing more plug-ins (select Help / Install New Software... in Eclipse's menu).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Compare page can give you some clarification
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php